# How to remove virtual machine from Hyper-V cluster?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, cluster-computing, wmi, hyper-v

There is a cluster node on which I create virtual machine:
[image]

After that I use method [AddVirtualMachine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh418102(v=vs.85).aspx) to add **existing** virtual machine to cluster.

[image]

But there is no corresponding method `DeleteVirtualMachine`.

If I simply remove virtual machine from a Node, then the following artefact is left on a cluster:
[image]

How can I remove my virtual machine from Hyper-V cluster via WMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decompiled `Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.dll` and found out that we need to use the WMI class [MSCluster_ResourceGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371465(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is how it can be done via powershell:

```
(Get-WmiObject -namespace root\mscluster -class MsCluster_ResourceGroup -filter "name='vm-name'").DestroyGroup()
```

Here is object model for [MSCluster_ResourceGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371465(v=vs.85).aspx) that I use in C# code:

```
public class MsResourceGroup : ManagementObjectWrapperBase
{
    public static MsResourceGroup Create(
        ManagementObject fromResourceGroupManagementObject)
    {
        var name = fromResourceGroupManagementObject.GetStringPropertyValue("Name");

        return new MsResourceGroup(
            name: name,
            resourceGroupManagementObject: fromResourceGroupManagementObject);
    }

    private MsResourceGroup(
        string name,
        ManagementObject resourceGroupManagementObject)
        : base(resourceGroupManagementObject)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public void DestroyGroup()
    {
        AsManagementObject.Invoke(
            methodName: "DestroyGroup",
            fillInvocationParameters: inputParameters => { });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "ManagementObjectWrapperBase". I am also not able to compile this code due to "GetStringPropertyValue". Can you please share complete files ?

Comment: Sorry Ghaffar, I couldn't share the complete source code even if I had access to it. This is ment as a concept, use it as an inspiration to write your own wrapper. The main thing here is that you need `MSCluster_ResourceGroup` object. You can study examples on microsoft docs to make that wrapper work - that is an easy part =)

Comment: Okay. I got it. Now I have deleted the object successfully using "DestroyGroup". Thank you for your help.